# FIRUser.uid changed to something and won't work in the swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to find the user's uid but it won't work because of the "newer" updates in firebase.
in the old version you could do this:

```
FIRUser.uid
```

but now it doens't work and I only figured out to  do this,

```
Auth.auth().currentUser.uid
```

and I don't need the users uid not the current user, seems kind of odd but if you use the current user you can't save more then one profile in firebase database. So if there is a way you can do it that will be great. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think you might just misunderstand what "current user" means.

There can only be one user signed into your app at any given moment on a specific device, and that's called the "current user", using the API provided by the SDK.  Other devices can have other users signed in - for those devices there will be different "current user".  When the user signs out, there is no longer a "current user" provided by the SDK.

These "current users" in no way impact the total number of user accounts that can be registered with your app.